# Trying to run lines on a timer

Tags: sql-server, command-line

One of the things I need to do on my job is run lines of SQL code.  I need to do each line individually.  Which involves highlighting one line, executing it, then doing the next.  Sometimes it is up to 50 lines, so I'm trying to find an easier way.

Not giving specifics, basically each line reads

```
UPDATE que SET status = 0 WHERE doc = '001'; EXECUTE [things] '001'

UPDATE que SET status = 0 WHERE doc = '002'; EXECUTE [things] '002'

UPDATE que SET status = 0 WHERE doc = '003'; EXECUTE [things] '003'
```

etc etc

Is there some kind of command that will do each line one after another?  preferably with like a 10 second timer inbetween?

Comment: Where is your data coming from? the doc = x, are those values in a table somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `WAITFOR DELAY` between executions.

```
UPDATE que SET status = 0 WHERE doc = '001'; EXECUTE [things] '001';
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:10';
UPDATE que SET status = 0 WHERE doc = '002'; EXECUTE [things] '002';
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:10';
UPDATE que SET status = 0 WHERE doc = '003'; EXECUTE [things] '003';
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:10';
```

Might be a good idea to add some (error) logging as to know where it failed if an error occured.

If you don't want to write 50 extra lines, you could use search and replace in ssms (CTRL+F) and replace 'UPDATE' with 'WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:10';  UPDATE'

[image]

Make sure you are on current document and then press replace all:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  My issue with that is that I would have to enter the delay line after every line.  At 50 some lines it would take more effort than save.  Would there be a line I could make at the start?  Like a "delay all following lines" kind of thing?

Comment: @Yuko added a find & replace all solution

Comment: Yeah that seems to work well.  Thank you Randi.